# navigate to an anchor in home page - angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

in angular2 onclick should redirect to an anchor in home page. I tried using `ng2-page-scroll` where navigation within a page is possible but not to other page. Here is what i tried.

```
onClickkk() {
    if(this.document.location.href.indexOf('resor') !== -1 ) {
      let pageScrollInstance: PageScrollInstance = PageScrollInstance.simpleInstance(this.document, '#app-give');
      this.pageScrollService.start(pageScrollInstance);

    }
  }
```

`this.document` causes to check #app-give in current page. However, i need to check that in some other page.

Comment: What is "current page" and "other page"?

Comment: current page : localhost:4200/#/resor
other page: localhost:4200/#/

Comment: Create a routerLink with a fragment. There should be examples out there but scrolling to a fragment doesn't work yet https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595#issuecomment-267816247

Comment: as per the link suggested, the code written on ngOnInit() will execute when the applicaiton initializes first time. How to run code in ngOnInit() when  onClickkk() gets triggered ?